# No User Info saved with Office 365 Login (ADAL.js)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365-apps, adal.js

I am using ADAL.js library for authenticating my Excel add-in via Office 365 Login. I am using an Azure AD application for this and have granted the required permissions too. The settings I have used with ADAL.js are below:

```
var config = {
    tenant: tenant,
    clientId: clientId,
    redirectUri: redirectUrl,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: logoutUrl,
    extraQueryParameter: 'scope=openid+profile',
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
};
```

The login works fine. It redirects properly to the add-in homepage but the user information is not retrievable using the `getCachedUser` function. All I get is a `null` value. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the adal library, Microsoft recommend using the `office-js-helpers` to authorize external services with the implicit flow.

Here is a code spinet to authenticate with Azure AD app:

```
var authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();

// register Microsoft (Azure AD 2.0 Converged auth) endpoint using
authenticator.endpoints.registerMicrosoftAuth('client id here');

// register Azure AD 1.0 endpoint using
authenticator.endpoints.registerAzureADAuth('client id here', 'tenant here');
```

**Authentication**

```
// for the default AzureAD endpoint
authenticator
    .authenticate(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.AzureAD)
    .then(function (token) { /* Microsoft Token */ })
    .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
```

**Getting a cached token**

```
authenticator
    .authenticate('name of endpoint')
    .then(function(token) {
    /*
        `token` is either cached or newly obtained upon expiry.
    */
    })
    .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);

authenticator
    .authenticate('name of endpoint', true /* force re-authentication */)
    .then(function(token) {
    /*
        `token` is newly obtained.
    */
    })
    .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);

// get the cached token if any. returns null otherwise.
var token = authenticator.tokens.get('name of endpoint');
```

More detail about this library, you can refer [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers). And below document is also helpful about authorize in Office add-in:

[Authorize external services in your Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins)

Comment: This seems closest to the solution I expected. Is there a way to get the email of the user?

Comment: @immysl AFAIK, this library doesn't support get the email(UPN?) of the user. As a workaround, you can get it by decoding the token.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out :)